# pip install jupyterlab fails in a Python 3.8 environment, Windows

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install jupyterlab on a Windows Machine, the installation fails with the below exception, I am using python 3.8.

```
C:\Users\ezily>pip install jupyterlab

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" (from jupyter-core>=4.6.1->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" (from jupyter-core>=4.6.1->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab)
```

Comment: Alright, what do you understand from that output? Have you done any research?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I don't know what to do. Sorry, I'm new to Python

Comment: Are you using virtual environments, or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install 3.7.6>= Python version. 
Jupyterlab was downloaded successfully